# Android: Changing image once the button is pressed and keeping it same

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want the image on the button to change once i click it. That means even if the button has been clicked once the new image should remain

Comment: That's a bad way to ask a question. You should provide the details of your implementation, post some code and describe what doesn't work for you. Right now it looks like you're asking someone to provide you a working solution.

Comment: the question is how to change the image or how to keep after the first click?

Comment: use the states checked/selected/pressed according to your wishes

Answer (score 1):

Do

`yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
yourButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourBackgroundImage);
});`

Answer (score 0):

1.You need to define states for your button and define background corresponding every state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />
</selector>
```

2. Change the state of button, once its clicked

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 button.setEnabled(true);
             }
         });
```